# Two regex functions together do not work

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to get the index for the start of a tag and the end of another tag. However, when I use one regex it works absolutely fine but for two regex functions, it gives an error for the second one.
Kindly help in explaining the reason

The below code works fine:

```
import re
f = open('C:/Users/Jyoti/Desktop/PythonPrograms/try.xml','r')
opentag = re.search('<TEXT>',f.read())
begin = opentag.start()+6
print begin
```

But when I add another similar regex it give me the error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'
```

which I understand is due to the `start()` function returning `None`

Below is the code:

```
import re
f = open('C:/Users/Jyoti/Desktop/PythonPrograms/try.xml','r')
opentag = re.search('<TEXT>',f.read())
begin = opentag.start()+6
print begin

closetag = re.search('</TEXT>',f.read())
end = closetag.start() - 1
print end
```

Please provide a solution to how can I get this working. Also I am a newbie here so please don't mind if I ask more questions on the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the file in [`f.read()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) which reads the whole file, and so the file descriptor moves forward, which means the text can't be read again when you do `f.read()` the next time.

If you need to search on the same text again, save the output of `f.read()`, and then do a regular expression search on it as below:

```
import re
f = open('C:/Users/Jyoti/Desktop/PythonPrograms/try.xml','r')

text = f.read()

opentag = re.search('<TEXT>',text)
begin = opentag.start()+6
print begin

closetag = re.search('</TEXT>',text)
end = closetag.start() - 1
print end
```

Comment: that works. Thanks!! But I have a question, if I have a very large file, say 1.5 GB, in that case will this be an optimized way?

Comment: @jyoti : It's probably a good idea not to start the 2nd search from the start of `text`. You can use `opentag.end()` to find the end of the match (rather that `opentag.start()+6`) and then start your next search from there.

Comment: @jyoti 1.5 GB is a small file if the RAM you have in your machine is 4GB or greater. In any case, `f.read()` reads the file in a single go, so this solution is as optimal as the approach in your question. As @PM2ring says in his comment, it is a good idea to search for the second string after the end of the first.

Comment: @jyoti In general, the StackOverflow format is one question per post, so if you have specific questions about optimizing this piece of code, feel free to ask an entirely new question and you can link this question there :)

Comment: thank you all. will surely post a new question if a need arises.

Answer (score 1):

`f.read()` reads the whole file. So there's nothing left to read on the second `f.read()` call.
See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: Cool. Although it *is* possible to extract some stuff from simple HTML/XML files, it's generally discouraged. And for large &/or complex files, it's a path to madness. :) Two popular HTML/XML parsing libraries are Beautiful Soup and lxml; Beautiful Soup is probably easier to learn, lxml is probably more powerful, and can be *much* faster in various situations. But SO is not the place to discuss opinions...

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to know that `f.read()` after read file sets the pointer to the `EOF` so if you again use f.read() it gives you empty string `''`. Secondly you should use `r` before string passed as a pattern of `re.search` function, which means raw, and automatically escapes special characters. So you have to do something like this:

```
import re
f = open('C:/Users/Jyoti/Desktop/PythonPrograms/try.xml','r')
data = f.read()
opentag = re.search(r'<TEXT>',data)
begin = opentag.start()+6
print begin

closetag = re.search(r'</TEXT>',data)
end = closetag.start() - 1
print end
```

gl & hf with Python :)